# React Native Web accessibility

Tags: reactjs, react-native, accessibility, wai-aria

I am currently working on a component that handles refinement filters in React Native Web. I need to have a screen reader (voiceover) announce when you delete one of these applied filters to the user. Currently I have the label set to `accessibilityLabel= 'Clear ' + refinment.title` I want it to read the label and then something like "Removed" when you fire off the removal. Any help and/or suggestions would be great! Thanks

Comment: I have tried using accessibiltyLiveRegion. Both 'polite' and 'assertive' but nothing is announcing when I remove the button.. There is an onPress function that causes the removal of the button from the screen, any ideas on associating a new accessibilityLabel into the onPress to announce "removed"??

Comment: Perhaps of interest... https://medium.com/dev-channel/why-authors-should-avoid-aria-relevant-5d3164fab1e3

Comment: Thank you for the reply Steve, I just tried using aria-relevant but unfortunately it is still not announcing when something has been removed from the <View>.

Comment: Yes, using aria-relevant seems inadvisable as the article notes. I wonder in your case if it’s necessary to announce removals since it seems this is the result of a user action. If you really feel it necessary, you could always push removal messages to a “screenreader only” (visibly hidden) aria-live region.

Comment: @steveax Yeah thats what I ended up having to do. I created a div with an aria-live region that passed in transparent text of the buttons title + 'removed' whenever it was pressed.